# Xcode 14 where is the assistant editor preview

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

In Xcode there used to be an assistant editor preview feature.  See this link: https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2017/01/24/preview-assistant-editor/

In Xcode 14 all I see is Automatic when selecting the assistant editor, no option for manual or preview.

Where is preview?

Comment: You've answered your own question: "used to be". Correct.  This no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

Editor -> Assistant(Click on any line) -> ⌥ ⌘ ⏎

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

You can open your UI interface file, be it XIBs or in Storybord and select the following option > Preview.

[image]

Comment: @Ahhishek What version of Xcode are you using? I do not see the option to select preview.  I only have options "Assistant" and "Layout" in the drop down section.  I see every option except "Preview".

Comment: I'm giving the answer a downvote because in my case the option being pointed at is not being shown.